# know if the Openwhisk action is executed on a prewarm container by receiving the log from API

Tags: portforwarding, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions, cold-start, kubernetes-container

I install openwhisk via kubernetes cluster. I invoke my actions through the API and also receive their logs via API. But in the log, it is only known whether the action is cold or warm, through initTime annotation. And it is not clear whether the cold action is executed on a cold container or preWarmed container. I tried to access this information through the user-events service and metrics endpoint via kubectl port forwarding and localhost:9095/metrics. But at this endpoint, only the cold start number is specified.
How do I know if the action is executed on a prewarm container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can only get this information by looking through the invoker logs.  I don't think we clearly distinguish between the two cases in the information that is directly associated with the activation.